# Declare properties in .h interface or in an extension in .m file?

Tags: objective-c, coding-style, declared-property

In Objective-C, is it best practice to:

1. Declare objects such as buttons in the .h and then synthesize in the .m

   ```
   .h
   @interface SomeViewController : UIViewController  
     @property (strong, nonatomic) UIButton *someButton;  
   @end

   .m
   @implementation SomeViewController  
     @synthesize someButton = _someButton;  
   @end
   ```
2. or declare them as ivars in the .m

   ```
   @interface SomeViewController ()  
     @property (strong, nonatomic) UIButton *someButton;  
   @end
   ```

I notice that in a lot of Apple code, specifically their Breadcrumbs sample code, many of their properties are declared in the interface. Is there a difference between the two? I also noticed that when properties are declared in the `@interface`, they are automatically synthesized with an underscore prefix, making the `someButton = _someButton` synthesis useless.

Comment: Both of those declarations are property declarations. The ivar is created by the `@synthesize`. They function identically; the difference is their visibility to other files.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

First, [as of Xcode 4.4](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ObjCAvailabilityIndex/index.html) there is no longer a need to `@synthesize`(unless you change both the setter and getter method), either when the `@property` is declared in the `@interface` or `@implementation`.

If the `@property` is only accessed from within the class then declare the `@property` in a [class extension](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH6-SW6) in the .m file. This provides encapsulation and make it easy to see that the `@property` is not used from another class.

If the `@property` is used by other classes, by design, then define it in the `@interface` in the .h file.

Comment: I'd like to comment that "it's rarely necessary to use `@synthesize`" anymore. (In some instances, such as readonly properties or properties on Core Data subclasses, it is actually still necessary to use `@synthesize` as Xcode still doesn't understand these very well.)

Comment: I totally agree with @JRG-Developer.

Comment: Here's a detailed discussion: [Automatic Property Synthesis With Xcode 4.4](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2012/08/01/property-synthesis-with-xcode-4-dot-4.html)

Comment: @Basil I check "Use Your Loaf" every week, great stuff! Thanks for the link.